# Not able to set sub-page on nginx

Tags: nginx

Sorry, if this is an easy to solve issue, but I'm fairly new with nginx and try to solve that issue for days now.

My issue is, that I want to display a self-made `index.html` under example.com/api, yet no matter what I try does it always show the 404-page.

To give some additional info:
I run an API, that runs on port 2000. I configured nginx, to change the port for all pages under /api.
The API itself provides images under /api/* (under different endpoints) and a list of all available endpoints as JSON under /api.json

Could it be an issue because of the port not being the normal one?

I put the `index.html` in `var/www/html/api` and even tried to set an `alias` in the `.conf` (In the `location /api` section) but that didn't work either.

Here's the `.conf` with the current settings. Note that every location except `/api` is unrelated to the page itself. Those are for a dashboard that runs on the main page itself, but I kept them in, in case that it does change something.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    open_file_cache          max=2000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;

    expires $expires;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    #error_page 404 /;
    #error_page 403 /;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    
$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location /vendor {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
    location /secret-key.txt {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        sendfile on;
    }
}

server {
    listen         443;
    server_name    www.example.com;
    return         301 https://example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

Comment: You are proxying `/api` to  `127.0.0.1:2000`. nginx doesn't look for local files on this path. You have to configure this on your backend server.

Comment: If you make a manual request for `http://127.0.0.1:2000/index.html`, do you receive an `index.html` with `wget` or `curl` utilities?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider (and Ivan)
I now found out, that this issue is because of my API itself, since the 404-page isn't the one provided through nginx.
And since the API isn't really related to this page, this question can most likely be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following location blocks in your config to serve the static `.html` file:

```
location /api {
    try_files $uri @upstream;
}

location @upstream {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2000;
    sendfile on;
}
```

This tells nginx to first to try to serve static files from root/api dir (`/var/www/html/api` in your case), and if none are found, then try the `@upstream` location which will send the request to upstream server.

Another option is to place the static HTML file in your application's root folder, if it is able to serve files that is.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all are you sure you need all these options to just serve an index.html?

When you proxy_pass something to lets say 127.0.0.1 means you get a request and pass it to another service that runs on that ip:port. So if you want to serve the index.html proxy_pass option will not work. Also you specify in root path until the /html folder and you did not add the api/ folder.

In any case i would suggest starting from a simpler configuration like the one bellow and built on it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example;
  return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/foo.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/bar.key;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384  EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA     RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";

  server_name example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      root /home/test//test.html;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Like I explained in my info is almost all stuff other than /api not really related to that and corresponds to a Web-Dashboard, that runs on the main page.
But I kept it in, for the case that it could actually cause problems.